# Is there a way to setup an audible alert in response to a reply or comment?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

It would be very convenient and useful to be able to be alerted by a notification sound when a question or answer has been replied to or commented on in one of the open tabs in my browser!

Does such a feature exist? If so, how do I enable it?!

Comment: I guess you could write a user script to do this.

Comment: @MartinSmith could you provide a reference as to how I would go about doing so? Thanks!

Comment: I've never written one myself (or even installed one written by someone else). Some probably very outdated info here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-apps-and-scripts/

Comment: There are several tools available on http://StackApps.com that monitor your inbox over the API and alert you.

Comment: @reubenjohn [How to make Stack Exchange behave exactly how you want it to](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/how-to-make-stack-exchange-behave-exactly-how-you-want-it-to/)

Comment: You could always download the app